# Como junto arquivos .txt de forma dinamica no python?

Tags: python, txt, arquivo-zip, merge

Boa tarde pessoal,

Tenho alguns logs em .txt que ficam num arquivo .zip , que são gerados de acordo com quando você pega esses logs no hardware em que estou trabalhando.
Estou tentando fazer alguma forma de mesclar (mergear) esses arquivos em um só, mas puxando de todos os dias, mas não estou conseguindo, com meu código atual eu puxo somente por um nome especifico do log, e não dinamicamente... no caso somente do dia 01-12-2022, mas precisarei puxar de vários dias diferentes, como faço isso?

Segue meu código:

```
import zipfile

zip_file = r'C:\Users\Viniz\Downloads\devkmbe-5511001_05-12-2022_00_20_09.zip'
pastaLog = 'devkmbe-5511001_05-12-2022_00_20_09'
nomesLogs = ['AudioCaptureMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt',
              'AudioMatchingMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt',
              'AudioWatermarkingMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt',
              'AwmDetectionLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'AwmDetectorLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'BackendMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt',
              'BatteryChargeControlLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'BatteryLifeMonitorLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'BluetoothCommsLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'BTRCLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'DashBoard_Communication_01_12_2022.txt',
              'DeliveryServiceMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt',
              'FileRotationControl_01_12_2022.txt',
              'InternetDataConsumptionLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'LAMLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'LcmMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt',
              'MainLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'MainProcessMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt',
              'NTPServerLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'OnOffLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'RTMDeliveryLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'SensorsPointerLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'SensorsProcessLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'StatusBitLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'StatusLog_01_12_2022.txt',
              'StorageStats_01_12_2022.txt',
              'WatchdogMemoryUsage_01_12_2022.txt']

logsMergeados = b''
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    for nomeLog in nomesLogs:
        with zip_ref.open(pastaLog + '/' + nomeLog) as f:
            logsMergeados += f.read()

    # Mergear em um novo arquivo
    novoArquivo = input("Coloque o nome do novo .txt: ")
    with open(novoArquivo, 'wb') as novoTxt:
        novoTxt.write(logsMergeados)

    print("Os logs foram mergeados com sucesso! ")
    print("Deseja ver o arquivo? (s / n): ")

    check = input()
    if check == 'n':
        exit()
    else:
        print()
        c = open(novoArquivo, "r")
        print(c.read())
        c.close()
```

Answer (score -3):

Você pode obter todas as datas num intervalo de datas e concatená-las com o nome de cada ficheiro.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

sdate = date(2022, 12, 1)
edate = date(2022, 12, 31)

dates = [sdate+timedelta(days=x) for x in range((edate-sdate).days)]

for dt in dates:
    print(dt.strftime("%d_%m_%Y"))
```